# OrderByChild() not working in Android Client

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my android application I am using following code

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    ref = database.getReference().child(Keys.CONTACTIFY_CONTACTS).child(sharedPrefs.getString(SharedPreferenceValues.CURRENT_USER_UID, "")).child(Keys.SHARED_CONTACTS);
    refer = ref.orderByChild(Keys.TIME);
 refer.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> sharedList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    Object[] rootData = ((HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue()).values().toArray();
                    for (Object singleElement :
                            rootData) {
                        HashMap<String, Object> eachElement = (HashMap<String, Object>) singleElement;
                        sharedList.add(eachElement);
                    }
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SharedItemsRecyclerViewAdapter(sharedList, mListener, getActivity()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

My firebase database structure is

[image]

My Firebase rules relevant to scenario are

```
    {
  "rules": {
  "mapper":{
       ".read": "auth!= null",
         ".write": "auth!= null"
    },
      "share_id_mapper":{
       ".read": "auth!= null",
         ".write": "auth!= null"
    },
       "contactify_contacts":{
                       //can read a message if authenticated
                 "$uid": {
                    "shared_contacts": {".indexOn": "time",
                            ".write": "auth!= null",
```

Problem is that I am getting the hasmap from snapshot in default sorted way i.e. the sortbyKey(). But I am expecting the result based on the value of time key in the node data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, the `DataSnapshot` it returns contains the keys, the values *and the order* of the results.

But then you convert the snapshot to a `Map`:

```
((HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue())
```

At this point the Firebase client has no other option than to drop the information about the order of the results.

The solution to this is to iterate over the snapshot's children with the methods from `DataSnapshot` and only then convert the values:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    List<String, Object> data = new ArrayList<String,Object>();
    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        data.add(childSnapshot.getKey(), childSnapshot.getValue());
    }
}
```

We recently added a sample of this to our [query documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data).

Comment: That works, however
List<String, Object> data = new ArrayList<String,Object>();
is kind of confusing, but rest was Okay  ;-) .

Comment: How about reversing the default order like ascending or descending?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)

Comment: thats what i did but I was hoping there may be some firebase query for that, thanks anyways